# nativescript-socketio connect() issue after upgrading

Tags: socket.io, connection, nativescript

i recently upgraded one of my projects to NS8 and thus nativescript-socketio to @triniwiz/nativescript-socketio.

Everything seems to work, but connect() does nothing, at all. No exception, no error. Juste nothing. I tried a blank project with just this in app.js :

```
import { SocketIO } from '@triniwiz/nativescript-socketio';
const socketIO = new SocketIO("http://1**.**.***.***:3001");

// connect
socketIO.connect();
```

And nothing happens, the server doesn't react.
The server works perfectly, i can reach it with other socket.io clients and a curl request without any problem.

```
curl "http://1**.**.***.***:3001/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling"
```

> 95:0{"sid":"wsR7LhpisXyHhQpxAAAB","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":2000,"pingTimeout":2000}2:40

Is there anything new i need to do in NS8 for nativescript-socketio to work properly ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i finally solved the problem, it was just because i fall back from https to http, and then having a cors policy issue.

Adding

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

To AndroidManifest.xml did the trick.

**From**

```
<application
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

**To**

```
<application
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```